# MySql Joining two tables

Tags: mysql

I am running into an issue while trying to join two MySQL tables and getting output.

My first table named `res` having 14 columns related to trains bookings. It has all the information of all trains with their date of Journey, available tickets, and their fares.

Table definition for `rest` .

```
CREATE TABLE  `abcd`.`rest` (
`PNR` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`Tr_Num` INT( 6 ) NULL ,
`Train_Name` VARCHAR( 60 ) NULL ,
`na` VARCHAR( 60 ) NULL ,
`age` INT( 3 ) NULL ,
`DOJ` DATE NULL ,
`seat` VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL ,
`src` VARCHAR( 60 ) NULL ,
`des` VARCHAR( 60 ) NULL ,
`class` VARCHAR( 60 ) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `PNR` )
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Table `rest`

This table has 10 columns

1. PNR=> Auto Increment. Primary. Int value
2. Train Number => Integer. Unique
3. Train Name => Varchar. Unique
4. Name of the passenger=> Varchar
5. Age => Int Value
6. date => date of Journey
7. Seating => Varchar
8. src => varchar
9. des => Varchar
10. class => varchar (ACI,ACII,ACIII,SL)

Table `res` and their attributes:

1. id=> Auto Increment.Primary Key
2. Train Number => Integer
3. Train Name => Varchar
4. src => Varchar
5. des => Varchar
6. date => date of Journey
7. AC_I => No of Tickets.Integer value
8. First_AC => Fare
9. AC_II => No of Tickets.Integer value
10. SEC_AC => Fare
11. AC_III => No of Tickets.Integer value
12. THIRD_Ac => Fare
13. SL=> No of Tickets for Sleeper Class.Integer value
14. SL_CLASS => Fare

The SQL command that I have used and was able to get something out of it but was not completely successful.

```
select rest.PNR, res.TRAIN_NUMBER,res.Tr_name,rest.na,rest.age, rest.doj,
rest.seat, rest.src, rest.des,rest.class, case when rest.class = 'AC I'then res.AC_I 
  when rest.class = 'AC II' then res.AC_II 
when rest.class = 'AC III' then res.AC_III 
when rest.class = 'Sleeper Class' then res.SL_CLASS 
end as Tickets
from rest, res where rest.DOJ = res.date order by PNR desc limit 2;
```

After running this command I get the output as below.

```
+-------+----------+----------+------+------+----------+------+------+------+------+--------+
| PNR   | TRAIN_NR | Tr_name  | Name | Age  | doj      | seat | src  | des  |class | Tickets|
+-------+----------+----------+------+------+----------+------+------+------+------+--------+
| 40    |  10008   |  Mum     |  S   |  42  |2018-04-27|  LB  |  M   |  H   | AC I |  480   |
+-------+----------+----------+------+------+----------+------+------+------+------+--------+
```

Now, What I am trying to do is along with this output I want to know fetch the **Fare** of the ticket.

I am expecting an output something like this.

```
+-------+----------+----------+------+------+----------+------+------+------+------+--------+--------+
| PNR   | TRAIN_NR | Tr_name  | Name | Age  | doj      | seat | src  | des  |class | Tickets| fare   |
+-------+----------+----------+------+------+----------+------+------+------+------+--------+--------+
| 40    |  10008   |  Mum     |  S   |  42  |2018-04-27|  LB  |  M   |  H   | AC I |  480   | ???    |
+-------+----------+----------+------+------+----------+------+------+------+------+--------+--------+
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please edit your post with `CREATE TABLE` statements and `INSERT` statements for sample data to reproduce the problem. Alternatively provide a link to db<>fiddle or similar

Comment: Lennart. I have created the table along with my DB from Php Myadmin. So, you can understand I have not created any DB/Tables with commands.

Comment: @Koushik.S - what Lennart meant was your post. Its easier to read if your table definition is like a "create table" script of sql and not like that

Comment: You can get the create table using `SHOW CREATE TABLE rest ;`

Answer (score 1):

```
select rest.PNR, res.TRAIN_NUMBER, res.Tr_name, res.AC_I, rest.na,rest.age
     , rest.doj, rest.seat, rest.src, rest.des, rest.class
     , case when rest.class = 'AC I' then res.FIRST_AC
            when rest.class = 'AC II' then res.SEC_AC 
            when rest.class = 'AC III' then res.THIRD_AC 
            when rest.class = 'Sleeper Class' then res.SL_CLASS 
       end as fare
     , case when rest.class = 'AC I' then  res.AC_I 
            when rest.class = 'AC II' then res.AC_II 
            when rest.class = 'AC III' then res.AC_III 
            when rest.class = 'Sleeper Class' then res.SL 
       end as tickets
from res, rest 
where rest.Tr_Num = res.TRAIN_NUMBER 
order by PNR desc limit 4 ;
```

Comment: Is that meant to be an answer or an edit to your question?

Comment: That's an answer.

Comment: Yeah, `CASE...` is the secret sauce.